# Lombok's @AllArgsConstructor doesn't work with final fields

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using Lombok's @AllArgsConstructor annotation to generate a constructor for my class, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to use it with final fields. Here's an example of what my class looks like:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {
  private final String field1;
  private final int field2;
}
```

When I try to create an instance of this class using the generated constructor, I get a compilation error:

```
MyClass.java:[X,Y] variable field1 might not have been initialized
```

I've checked that I've initialized the final fields correctly in my code, so I suspect that there's an issue with Lombok's @AllArgsConstructor annotation. How can I use @AllArgsConstructor with final fields in Lombok?

Comment: Perhaps need to use `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.  But since all those fields are `final`, then probably could use `@Value` instead of `@Data`.

Comment: What version of lombok? For 1.18.x, lombok is smart enough to not generate setters for final fields.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with lombok 1.18.26 (and according to the [lombok documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) it is clear that the created constructor initializes all fields). Can you provide more context? How do you create an instance of this class? What is the code where the compile error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add force to your annotation. By adding force lombok should generate a constructor with final fields

```
@AllArgsConstructor(force = true)
```

Comment: not working.. Version?